# Card con React.js

Tags: reactjs, card

soy nuevo usand React asi que trato de hacer ejercicios para mejorar, la cuestion es que el ejercicio trata de cards, y queda como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando quiero que quede asi, en medio de la pagina, que se muestren por completo todos los cards con su forma en su totalidad, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi mismo si trato de meter un titulo en la pagina, que se quede sujetado a la parte superior central, este se repite 1 vez por cada card.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**card-style**:

```
    .card{
    width: 18rem;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.253) !important;
}


.card-text{
    font-size: .9rem;
    padding: 0.4rem
}

.container .row{
    padding-top: -8px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    
}
```

**CardUI**:

```
import React from "react";
import "./card-style.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Section = styled.section`
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;

  margin: 0 auto;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontBig};
  font-family: "Kaushan Script";
  font-weight: 300;

  position: fixed;
  top: -0.6rem;
  left: 24%;
  z-index: 5;

`;


const Card = props =>{
  return (
    <Section>
    <Title>
      About Us
    </Title>

   <div className="card text-center">
     <div className="overflow">
       <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="Image1" className="card-img-top"></img>
     </div>
     <div className="card-body text-dark">
       <h4 className="card-title">{props.title}</h4>
       <p className="card-text text-secondary">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Magnam deserunt fuga accusantium excepturi quia.
       </p>
       <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-success">Go anywhere</a>
       </div> 
   </div>
   </Section>
  );
}


    

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, el título lo tienes que sacar del componente Card y ponerlo antes de la lista que renderiza las Card para que solo salga una vez.

Segundo, envuelve la lista que renderiza las Card en un componente y dale la altura que necesitas, luego ya solo tienes que posicionar dicho componente en el lugar que quieras de la página con css.